# Merge [dual-monitor] and [triple-monitor] into [multiple-monitors]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I don't really know a lot about [dual-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitor), [triple-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/triple-monitor) or [multiple-monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors) setups, but it seems logical to move [dual-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitor) and [triple-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/triple-monitor) into [multiple-monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors) since "multiple" refers to 2+.

I think it would be better to have all the questions in one tag instead of three. Many questions about dual-monitor setup [(like this one)](https://superuser.com/questions/515407/my-dual-screen-wallpapers-dont-line-up-correctly) are only tagged with [multiple-monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors), anyway [(or with both tags in many cases)](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitor+multiple-monitors). Same goes for [triple-monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/triple-monitor+multiple-monitors).

Comment: Definitely seems like a logical proposition

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can see nothing wrong with the proposal. Would merge+synonymize.

---

#### [dual-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitor)

```
updating post history, 247 rows affected
updating posts, 204 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 159 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [multiple-monitors] and [dual-monitor] complete!
remapping 1 synonyms
6 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym dual-monitor -> multiple-monitors was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```

---

#### [triple-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/triple-monitor)

```
updating post history, 28 rows affected
updating posts, 23 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 16 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [multiple-monitors] and [triple-monitor] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym triple-monitor -> multiple-monitors was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```